# Verify E-Mail with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, email

I want to submit my form and that a AJAX Call should send that data to my php file. In my php file is a e-mail validation with `filter_var` and if it the validation returns false the respond should get back to Javascript. Besides the validation part it works great. But everytime I want to submit and check if it is a valid email it returns false with "Please enter a valid email". Equal if it is a valid or false email address.

**UPDATED - 09.08.2014/04:12**
Now it works basically **BUT** if it has no errormessage I get an Issue `Cannot read proberty "isError" of null` which is logical. But don't know how to avoid that issue to pass it correctly back to javascript.

**HTML**

```
<form action="submit.php" id="SubmitForm" method="post">
  <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text" />
 </form>
 <button id="submitAll">
   <span>Submit</span>
 </button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function submit() {
    var $form = $('form#SubmitForm');
    $.post(
    $form.attr('action'),
    $form.serialize(),

    function (data) {
        if (data.isError) {
            $errMsg.empty().text('Please enter a valid email');
        } else {
            document.location.href = "submit.php"
        }
    },'json'); }
```

**PHP**

```
$profileEmail  = $_POST['mail'];
$errorMessages = array();

if(!filter_var($profileEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errorMessages[] = "* Please enter a valid e-mail";
} else {
    $errorMessages[] = "* Valid e-mail";
}

if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
    die(json_encode(array('isError' => true, 'errorMessages' => $errorMessages)));
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending a string to the server to perform a pattern match on it? That can be handled entirely in JS.

Comment: @Quentin you've been around here long enough that you should know that valid email address checking is hard enough that you can't perform any sort of simple client side match.  The only feasible test is one that performs actual DNS lookups on the domain name part of the supplied address.

Comment: Actually - there is _one_ valid test you can make client side - does the address have an `@` in it.  But even that's not fool proof because it has to be one that hasn't been quoted in the local part - `"foo@bar"@example.com` is actually a legal address.

Comment: OP - just try a simple form first without the AJAX - the `filter_var` code _looks_ OK, so try doing some debugging around your parameter passing etc and get that working first before introducing AJAX and its potential failure modes into the equation.

Comment: The fact that I'm validate email adress per php is that you can easily turn of javascript and the javascript validation.

Comment: @Alnitak — The point was that the server was only doing a pattern match on it in the first place.

Comment: @OliverKindermann — Using JavaScript to send the data to the server for testing won't solve the problem of "Can be bypassed by turning off JS". You need to test when the regular form submission is done instead of trying to use Ajax to do it before the form has been completed.

Comment: @Quentin that's fair, and even though it's PHP (ugh) I'd trust a maintained function there to do a better job than homebrewed logic on the client side.

Comment: @Quentin - The point is that the form without javascript sends to a validation.php in real. Only if the validation.php pass no errors you will get with javascript access to the submit.php. That wasn't mentioned in the code above, because it wasn't neccessary for my problem. So No Javascript = No Entrance to submit.php.

Please let me know if you disagree. I'm no real programmer and yes it is all "homebrewed logic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple - you've given your input field an ID (`mail`), but *not* a `name`, and therefore the serialization isn't working - you're just sending an empty query string to the server.

You need:

```
<input id="mail" name="mail" type="text" />
```

I always use both a name and ID because form submission requires the former, but DOM manipulation is (much) easier using the latter.

**EDIT** to avoid the new problem you've discovered after fixing the above, simply ensure that your script always returns some valid JSON, even if it's just `{}`.  You've asked the server for some JSON - you have to return some.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED - 09.08.2014/04:28**
Now it works! I realize that my `if(data.isError)` operator was wrong. The code below works. Thank you for the useful input to solve the problem. :)

**HTML**

```
<form action="submit.php" id="SubmitForm" method="post">
    <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text" />
</form>
<button id="submitAll">
    <span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function submit() {
    var $form = $('form#SubmitForm');
    $.post(
    $form.attr('action'),
    $form.serialize(),

    function (data) {
        if (data && data.isError) {
            $errMsg.empty().text('Please enter a valid email');
        } else {
            document.location.href = "submit.php"
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

**PHP**

```
$profileEmail  = $_POST['mail'];
$errorMessages = array();

if(!filter_var($profileEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errorMessages[] = "* Please enter a valid e-mail";
} else {
    $errorMessages[] = "* Valid e-mail";
}

if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
    die(json_encode(array('isError' => true, 'errorMessages' => $errorMessages)));
}
```

Comment: Your original `if` test works fine so long as you _always_ send back some valid JSON, which of course you should.  The fundamental problem was still your missing `name` field.  However you've now edited that back into the original question - that's not how it's supposed to work here.

Comment: Yes you're right. The fundamental problem was that simple mistake thay my `name="mail"` wasn't equal to `$_POST["submitMail"]` thanks for that. I **deleted** it in my first code snipped because I thought it isn't necessary for this problem and I thought the `$_POST` get the ID-Tag and not the name-Tag. The further issue was that JSON returns the object instead of ignore the property isError if php returns null.